# Product Item: Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've trouble finding a good solution fo a relativly simple responsive layout problem.

It's a product item component which should look like in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8dBd.png).

It brings some sort of equal-height-requirement with it (on desktop img to other content and on mobile img to product-info).

As stand alone it woudnt be a problem but i struggle with finding a good practice for two different viewports without duplicate content/markup.

Main Problem is the wrapping/flow-behaviour. Usually i would place a wrapper arround info and detail, but because of the mobile version this isn't possible.

Can maybe give me someone a good hint how to solve my problem?

Would be much appreciated

Thx and greetings, eldaDev

```css
.product-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.product-item__image {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.product-item__info {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: green;
}

.product-item__detail {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Markup example mobile version alike -->
<div class="product-item">
  <div class="product-item__image">img</div>
  <div class="product-item__info">info content</div>
  <div class="product-item__detail">detail content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .product-item {
  
}
 .product-item__image img{width:100%}
.product-item__image {
     float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ffd9d9;
}

.product-item__info {
 float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
  
 }
.product-item__detail {
 
 float: left;
    width: 80%;
    background: #bfbfbf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
  
}
 
@media  (max-width: 767px) {
.product-item__image {
 float: left;
 width:20%;  
}

.product-item__info {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 120px 0;
}
.product-item__detail {
    float: none;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: #bfbfbf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
    clear: both;
}
 }
```

```html
<div class="product-item">
 <div class="product-item__image">img</div>
  <div class="product-item__info">info content</div>
  <div class="product-item__detail">detail content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?  Chunks of code on their own are generally not preferred on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It is working for me. `float` and `@media()` used to make it responsive. If not work, then let me know. Its my pleasure to help others :)

```css
*{
  font-family: arial;
  color: #aaa;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.wrapper{
  border: solid 1px #363636;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}


.image{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
  border: solid 1px #363636;
}

.images > img{
  height: 90%;
}

.product_info{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border: solid 1px #363636;
  width: 77%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}


.product_detail{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: solid 1px #363636;
  width: 99%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 85px;
}


@media(max-width: 767px;){

  .image{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px #363636;
  }
  
  .product_detail{
      float: right;
      margin-top: 2%;
      margin-left: 22%;
      border: solid 1px #363636;
      width: 77%;
      text-align: center;
      height: 85px;
    }

}
```

```html
<center>Desktop</center>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8dBds.png" alt="IMG">
  </div>
  
  <div class="product_info">
    <h1>Product Info</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product_detail">
    <h1>Product Detail</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```